# getting error - System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled

Tags: c#, multithreading, invalidoperationexception

I have just started to learn windows application development, and we have been given self learn project to develop one windows application. I am trying to create the application to send email. I have created a class `MsgSender.cs` to handle that. When I call that class from main form I am getting the following error

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled.

Error Message-->

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'pictureBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`

The stacktrace is as follows:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
Message=Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'pictureBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
Source=System.Windows.Forms
StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)
   at UltooApp.Form1.sendMethod() in D:\Ultoo Application\UltooApp\UltooApp\Form1.cs:line 32
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException:
```

Code:

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        count++;
        lblMsgStatus.Visible = false;
        getMsgDetails();
        msg = txtMsg.Text;

        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(sendMethod));
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
    }

    void sendMethod()
    {
        string lblText = (String)MsgSender.sendSMS(to, msg, "hotmail", uname, pwd);
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        lblMsgStatus.Visible = true;
        lblMsgStatus.Text = lblText + "\nFrom: " + uname + " To: " + cmbxNumber.SelectedItem + " " + count;
    }
```

Comment: check that the inner exception doesn't have any useful info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`You can access Form GUI controls in GUI thread` and **you are trying to access outside GUI thread that is the reason for getting exception**. You can use MethodInvoker to access controls in the GUI thread.

```
void sendMethod()
{
    MethodInvoker mi = delegate{
       string lblText = (String) MsgSender.sendSMS(to, msg, "hotmail", uname, pwd);
       pictureBox1.Visible = false;
       lblMsgStatus.Visible = true;
       lblMsgStatus.Text = 
             lblText + "\nFrom: " + uname + 
             " To: " + cmbxNumber.SelectedItem + " " + count;
   }; 

   if(InvokeRequired)
       this.Invoke(mi);
}
```