# Use of unassgined variable, how do I return a bitmap from another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, bitmap

I made this script that downloads a image but to improve GUI responsiveness I wanted to make a new thread but how do I return the bitmap back to the GUI thread?

My code :

```
        try
        {
            Bitmap bit;

            var t = new Thread((ThreadStart)(() =>
            {
                string picUri = "";

                if (ONLINE_MODE_CHKBOX.Checked)
                {
                    picUri = "http://minecraft.aggenkeech.com/body.php?u=" + GetSessionId(true) + "&s=128&r=255&g=250&b=238";
                }
                else
                    picUri = "http://minecraft.aggenkeech.com/body.php?u=%USERNAME%&s=128&r=255&g=250&b=238";


                picUri = picUri.Replace("%USERNAME%", USERNAME_TXT.Text);

                // Create the requests.
                WebRequest requestPic = WebRequest.Create(picUri);

                WebResponse responsePic = requestPic.GetResponse();

                Image webImage = Image.FromStream(responsePic.GetResponseStream());

                Color red = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 250, 238);

                bit = new Bitmap(webImage);

                bit.MakeTransparent(red);
            }));
            t.Start();

            SKIN_PICTURE_BOX.Image = bit; //<<<< Here it returns an error : Error, Use of unasigned local variable 'bit'

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to simply set `Bitmap bit = null;`

Comment: Yes, than the bitmap doesn't load into the picture box

Comment: You set immediately image to SKIN_PICTURE_BOX before thread finishes its work. So it is null. `async/await` can help here..

Comment: So I should first let it wait till the thread is exited?

Comment: @Nobleleader13245 use `async/await` or a callback mechanism. (don't do busy-waiting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a public event and call that trigger that event from the thread, You can read more how to add / consume events over [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4773/Events-and-Delegates-Simplified).

```
public delegate void GetBitMapDelegate(Bitmap bit);
public event GetBitMapDelegate GetBitMap;

//Your method
try
{
    Bitmap bit;

    var t = new Thread((ThreadStart)(() =>
    {
        string picUri = "";

        if (ONLINE_MODE_CHKBOX.Checked)
        {
            picUri = "http://minecraft.aggenkeech.com/body.php?u=" + GetSessionId(true) + "&s=128&r=255&g=250&b=238";
        }
        else
            picUri = "http://minecraft.aggenkeech.com/body.php?u=%USERNAME%&s=128&r=255&g=250&b=238";


        picUri = picUri.Replace("%USERNAME%", USERNAME_TXT.Text);

        // Create the requests.
        WebRequest requestPic = WebRequest.Create(picUri);

        WebResponse responsePic = requestPic.GetResponse();

        Image webImage = Image.FromStream(responsePic.GetResponseStream());

        Color red = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 250, 238);

        bit = new Bitmap(webImage);

        bit.MakeTransparent(red);
        GetBitMap(bit);
    }));
    t.Start();

    SKIN_PICTURE_BOX.Image = bit; //<<<< Here it returns an error : Error, Use of unasigned local variable 'bit'

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Consume this event in Form class when you will call the method for generating thread you will get the event.

Comment: You need to consume the event on the form class, you are getting exception because the event is not being consumed.

Comment: I guess, @Nobleleader13245's next exception will be *cross-thread operation*

Comment: For cross thread exception you can follow this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411194/getting-error-system-invalidoperationexception-was-unhandled

Comment: @Nobleleader13245, I found nice article about events here, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4773/Events-and-Delegates-Simplified

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .Net 4.5, you can use `async/await` which can make your life easier. (No need for events,delegates, *"Invokes"* s etc.)

```
this.BackgroundImage = await GetImageAsync("http://......");
```

---

```
async Task<Image> GetImageAsync(string url)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(await client.GetStreamAsync(url));

        Color transparent = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 250, 238);
        bmp.MakeTransparent(transparent);

        return bmp;
    }
}
```