# vb.net error creating form

Tags: vb.net, forms

I am currently creating a small piece of software for a little project. But when I am trying to open another form I get an error. I have attached all of the error and form code below. I literally only just started the project and I am getting these errors which I have never received before. I'll probably shoot myself in the foot for missing something really simple.

**Error**

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233079
Message=An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "WindowsApplication2.AddBookingForm.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "WindowsApplication2" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
Source=WindowsApplication2
StackTrace:
   at WindowsApplication2.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create__Instance__[T](T Instance) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 190
   at WindowsApplication2.My.MyProject.MyForms.get_AddBookingForm()
   at WindowsApplication2.MainForm.AddButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsApplication2\WindowsApplication2\MainForm.vb:line 4
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at WindowsApplication2.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException: System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException
   HResult=-2146233038
   Message=Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "WindowsApplication2.AddBookingForm.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "WindowsApplication2" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
   Source=mscorlib
   StackTrace:
        at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String fileName)
        at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
        at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
        at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
        at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name, CultureInfo culture, Boolean wrapUnmanagedMemStream)
        at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name)
        at WindowsApplication2.AddBookingForm.InitializeComponent() in C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsApplication2\WindowsApplication2\AddNewBooking.Designer.vb:line 234
        at WindowsApplication2.AddBookingForm..ctor()
   InnerException:
```

**MainForm**

```
Public Class MainForm

Private Sub AddButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddButton.Click
    AddBookingForm.Show()
End Sub

End Class
```

**AddBookingForm**

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _ Partial Class AddBookingForm
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Dim resources As System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager = New System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(GetType(AddBookingForm))
    Me.Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.Label2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.Label3 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.Label4 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.Label5 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.Label6 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.Label7 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.Label8 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.SearchButton = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.AddJobNoText = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.AddNameText = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.AddPhoneList = New System.Windows.Forms.ListBox()
    Me.AddAddressText = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.AddTypeCombo = New System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox()
    Me.AddTimeCombo = New System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox()
    Me.AddDatePicker = New System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker()
    Me.AddOtherText = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.AddAddButton = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.AddExitButton = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'Label1
    '
    Me.Label1.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(24, 15)
    Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
    Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(67, 13)
    Me.Label1.TabIndex = 0
    Me.Label1.Text = "Job Number:"
    '
    'Label2
    '
    Me.Label2.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(53, 51)
    Me.Label2.Name = "Label2"
    Me.Label2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(38, 13)
    Me.Label2.TabIndex = 1
    Me.Label2.Text = "Name:"
    '
    'Label3
    '
    Me.Label3.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(5, 87)
    Me.Label3.Name = "Label3"
    Me.Label3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(86, 13)
    Me.Label3.TabIndex = 2
    Me.Label3.Text = "Phone Numbers:"
    '
    'Label4
    '
    Me.Label4.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label4.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(43, 197)
    Me.Label4.Name = "Label4"
    Me.Label4.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(48, 13)
    Me.Label4.TabIndex = 3
    Me.Label4.Text = "Address:"
    '
    'Label5
    '
    Me.Label5.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label5.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(37, 285)
    Me.Label5.Name = "Label5"
    Me.Label5.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(54, 13)
    Me.Label5.TabIndex = 4
    Me.Label5.Text = "Job Type:"
    '
    'Label6
    '
    Me.Label6.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label6.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(58, 321)
    Me.Label6.Name = "Label6"
    Me.Label6.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(33, 13)
    Me.Label6.TabIndex = 5
    Me.Label6.Text = "Time:"
    '
    'Label7
    '
    Me.Label7.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label7.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(58, 357)
    Me.Label7.Name = "Label7"
    Me.Label7.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(33, 13)
    Me.Label7.TabIndex = 6
    Me.Label7.Text = "Date:"
    '
    'Label8
    '
    Me.Label8.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label8.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 392)
    Me.Label8.Name = "Label8"
    Me.Label8.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(91, 13)
    Me.Label8.TabIndex = 7
    Me.Label8.Text = "Other Information:"
    '
    'SearchButton
    '
    Me.SearchButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(215, 12)
    Me.SearchButton.Name = "SearchButton"
    Me.SearchButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(59, 20)
    Me.SearchButton.TabIndex = 8
    Me.SearchButton.Text = "Search"
    Me.SearchButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'AddJobNoText
    '
    Me.AddJobNoText.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(93, 12)
    Me.AddJobNoText.Name = "AddJobNoText"
    Me.AddJobNoText.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(116, 20)
    Me.AddJobNoText.TabIndex = 9
    '
    'AddNameText
    '
    Me.AddNameText.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(93, 48)
    Me.AddNameText.Name = "AddNameText"
    Me.AddNameText.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(181, 20)
    Me.AddNameText.TabIndex = 10
    '
    'AddPhoneList
    '
    Me.AddPhoneList.FormattingEnabled = True
    Me.AddPhoneList.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(93, 84)
    Me.AddPhoneList.Name = "AddPhoneList"
    Me.AddPhoneList.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(181, 95)
    Me.AddPhoneList.TabIndex = 11
    '
    'AddAddressText
    '
    Me.AddAddressText.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(93, 194)
    Me.AddAddressText.Multiline = True
    Me.AddAddressText.Name = "AddAddressText"
    Me.AddAddressText.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(181, 73)
    Me.AddAddressText.TabIndex = 12
    '
    'AddTypeCombo
    '
    Me.AddTypeCombo.FormattingEnabled = True
    Me.AddTypeCombo.Items.AddRange(New Object() {"Pickup", "Delivery", "Tune-In", "Set-Up", "Antenna", "Other"})
    Me.AddTypeCombo.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(93, 282)
    Me.AddTypeCombo.Name = "AddTypeCombo"
    Me.AddTypeCombo.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(181, 21)
    Me.AddTypeCombo.TabIndex = 13
    '
    'AddTimeCombo
    '
    Me.AddTimeCombo.FormattingEnabled = True
    Me.AddTimeCombo.Items.AddRange(New Object() {"AM", "PM"})
    Me.AddTimeCombo.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(93, 318)
    Me.AddTimeCombo.Name = "AddTimeCombo"
    Me.AddTimeCombo.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(181, 21)
    Me.AddTimeCombo.TabIndex = 14
    '
    'AddDatePicker
    '
    Me.AddDatePicker.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(93, 354)
    Me.AddDatePicker.Name = "AddDatePicker"
    Me.AddDatePicker.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(181, 20)
    Me.AddDatePicker.TabIndex = 15
    '
    'AddOtherText
    '
    Me.AddOtherText.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(93, 389)
    Me.AddOtherText.Multiline = True
    Me.AddOtherText.Name = "AddOtherText"
    Me.AddOtherText.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(181, 61)
    Me.AddOtherText.TabIndex = 16
    '
    'AddAddButton
    '
    Me.AddAddButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(42, 459)
    Me.AddAddButton.Name = "AddAddButton"
    Me.AddAddButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(89, 23)
    Me.AddAddButton.TabIndex = 17
    Me.AddAddButton.Text = "Add Booking"
    Me.AddAddButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'AddExitButton
    '
    Me.AddExitButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(152, 459)
    Me.AddExitButton.Name = "AddExitButton"
    Me.AddExitButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(89, 23)
    Me.AddExitButton.TabIndex = 18
    Me.AddExitButton.Text = "Exit"
    Me.AddExitButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'AddBookingForm
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(283, 491)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.AddExitButton)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.AddAddButton)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.AddOtherText)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.AddDatePicker)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.AddTimeCombo)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.AddTypeCombo)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.AddAddressText)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.AddPhoneList)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.AddNameText)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.AddJobNoText)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.SearchButton)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label8)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label7)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label6)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label5)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label4)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label3)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label2)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label1)
    Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle
    Me.Icon = CType(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon"), System.Drawing.Icon)
    Me.MaximizeBox = False
    Me.Name = "AddBookingForm"
    Me.Text = "Add New Booking"
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.PerformLayout()

End Sub
Friend WithEvents Label1 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents Label2 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents Label3 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents Label4 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents Label5 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents Label6 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents Label7 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents Label8 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents SearchButton As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents AddJobNoText As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents AddNameText As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents AddPhoneList As System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
Friend WithEvents AddAddressText As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents AddTypeCombo As System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
Friend WithEvents AddTimeCombo As System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
Friend WithEvents AddDatePicker As System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
Friend WithEvents AddOtherText As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents AddAddButton As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents AddExitButton As System.Windows.Forms.Button

Private Sub AddExitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddExitButton.Click
    'AddJobNoText.Clear()
    'AddNameText.Clear()
    'AddOtherText.Clear()
    'AddAddressText.Clear()
    'AddPhoneList.Text = ""
    'AddTypeCombo.Text = ""
    'AddTimeCombo.Text = ""
    'Me.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: do you have anything on `AddBookingForm_Load` or `AddBookingForm_Activated` or `AddBookingForm_shown`  ??!!

Comment: Nope nothing. The entire code is in the OP.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411194/getting-error-system-invalidoperationexception-was-unhandled .

Comment: So anything written on `New()` in  `AddBookingForm.designer.vb` ??

Comment: Have you tried re-adding the icon in the form designer?  It's the only thing using a resource.

Comment: bookingform does not look valid.  there is no constructor and something looks like it did not serialize correctly.  you are also using the default instance which is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try below and Comment

```
Private Sub AddButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddButton.Click
  with AddBookingForm
     .Mdiparent = Me 'here me is the MDIParent form in your case `MainForm`
     .Show()
     .Focus()
  End With
End Sub
```